# Alguie podria ayudarme porque me sale este error en c#

Tags: c#

El error me lo da en parámetros en esta parte

Me dice

> No se puede convertir sapestructura a system collections.Generic.List.
>   enSAPConector.EjecutarFuncionSAP("ZMM_B2B_ENC_RESPUESTA", parametros);

```
 public class RespuestaEncuestaRepository
    {
        public ResprovSolicitudModel EnviarEncuesta(ResprovSolicitudModel value)
        {
            ResprovSolicitudModel respuesta = new ResprovSolicitudModel();


            SAPEstructura parametros = new SAPEstructura();
            //Dictionary<string, object> parametros = new Dictionary<string, object>();
           // Dictionary<string, object> tablasSalida = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            List<DataTable> datos = new List<DataTable>();

            SAPTabla MB1B = new SAPTabla { NombreTabla = "RESPROV" };

            foreach (var variable in value.ListaEncuesta)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> elemento = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                elemento.Add("SECCION", variable.SECCION);
                elemento.Add("PREG", variable.PREG);
                elemento.Add("CONS", variable.CONS);
                elemento.Add("TIPO", variable.TIPO);
                elemento.Add("RESP", variable.RESP);
                MB1B.Parametros.Add(elemento);
            }

            parametros.Parametros.Add("RESPROV", MB1B);
            parametros.Parametros.Add("E_LIFNR", "0000254142"/*Common.RellenarIzquierda(value.CuentaSAP)*/);
            //parametros.Add("E_SPRAS", value.IdiomaSAPId);
            //tablasSalida.Add("RESPROV", new DataTable());

           SAPConector.EjecutarFuncionSAP("ZMM_B2B_ENC_RESPUESTA", parametros);



            return respuesta;

        }
    }
}
```

Esta es la función EjecutarFuncionSAP.

```
public static MessageModel EjecutarFuncionSAP(string NameFunction, List<SAPEstructura> value)
        {
            MessageModel message = new MessageModel();
            RfcDestination rfcDestination = null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SYSID_SAP"]))
            {
                rfcDestination = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SYSID_SAP"].ToString());
                if (rfcDestination != null)
                {
                    //Crea la instancia de la funcion
                    IRfcFunction funcion = rfcDestination.Repository.CreateFunction(NameFunction);

                    //Genera un listado para agregar las estructura que vaya a contener
                    List<IRfcStructure> Estructuras = new List<IRfcStructure>();

                    //Itera cada una de las estructuras
                    foreach (SAPEstructura estructuraSAP in value)
                    {
                        if (estructuraSAP.NombreEstructura == string.Empty)
                        {
                            foreach (var parametro in estructuraSAP.Parametros)
                            {
                                funcion.SetValue(parametro.Key, parametro.Value);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Obtiene el tipo de estructura actual
                            IRfcStructure tempStruct = funcion.GetStructure(estructuraSAP.NombreEstructura);

                            //Agrega los N parametros que contiene
                            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> param in estructuraSAP.Parametros)
                            {
                                tempStruct.SetValue(param.Key, param.Value);
                            }

                            //Agrega al listado
                            Estructuras.Add(tempStruct);
                        }
                    }

                    //Ejecuta la funcion
                    funcion.Invoke(rfcDestination);

                    message.Status = 1;
                    message.Message = "GrlMsgExitoConsulta";
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error al crear RFCDestination.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("La cadena de conexion [SYSID_SAP] para SAP no esta configurada en el archivo .config.");
            }

            return message;
        }
```

Comment: Buenas tardes, nos puedes mostrar como esta declarado la función EjecutarFuncionSAP , da la impresión que espera una lista de objetos y tu solo le estas enviando un objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Debes modificar esta línea:

```
SAPEstructura parametros = new SAPEstructura();
```

Debe ser una lista - eso es lo que espera la otra función `List<SAPEstructura>`.

Lo que pasa es que ahora el parámetro es una lista, debes tener 2 variables `SAPEstructura parametros = new SAPEstructura();` y `List ListaParametros = new List();` luego que agregues los datos en parámetros lo agregas en la variable `ListaParametros` y esa es la variable que le pases a la función.

Comment: Hola Muchas gracias ya lo hice. Ahora me da error en esta parte en el Add 
 me dice que void List<SAPEstructura>.Add(SAPEstructura item)  Adds an object to the end of the List<T> Ninguna sobrecarga para el metodo Add toma 2 argumentos. Disculpen soy algo novato en esto de la programacion jeje.                 parametros.Add("RESPROV", MB1B);
parametros.Add("E_LIFNR", "0000254142"/*Common.RellenarIzquierda(value.CuentaSAP)*/)

Comment: lo que pasa es que ahora parametros es una lista, debes tener 2 variables SAPEstructura parametros = new SAPEstructura();  y List<SAPEstructura> Listaparametros = new List<SAPEstructura>();  luego que agregues los datos en parametros lo agregas en la variable ListaParametros y esa es la variable que le pases a la función

Comment: @Mayenoe, por favor agrega tu comentario en tu respuesta. Los comentarios son temporales. Noé, si esta respuesta responde a tu pregunta, recuerda [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score -2):

lo que pasa es que ahora parametros es una lista, debes tener 2 variables `SAPEstructura parametros = new SAPEstructura();` y `List<SAPEstructura> Listaparametros = new List<SAPEstructura>();` luego que agregues los datos en parametros lo agregas en la variable ListaParametros y esa es la variable que le pases a la función

Comment: no añadas otra respuesta. En sul lugar, edita la respuesta que diste en su momento. Si consideras que tu respuesta contesta la pregunta, y hay una nueva duda, se necesita una nueva pregunta.